# Total beginner here (Liquid elsif command)

Tags: liquid

I have a form that sends custom field data to my newsletter software.
There I have implemented a TAG.
When writing an email I have the option to use personalizations (which are Liquid commands).

I was told I could do this:

{% if subscriber.tags contains "TagName1" %} The subscriber has the tag 1 message here

{% elsif subscriber.tags contains "TagName2" %} The subscriber has the tag 2 add your message here

{% elsif subscriber.tags contains "TagName3" %} The subscriber has the tag 3 add your message here

{% else %} The subscriber does not have the tag {% endif %}

Anyone that has TagName1 will only receive "The subscriber has the tag 1 message here".

My questions:
using the above, can I get more than one TagNme recognized? For example if customer is tagged with TagName 2 and TagName 3 (but not 1),

I would see:
"The subscriber has the tag 2 message here"
"The subscriber has the tag 3 message here"

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `or` statement, documented here: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/operators/

```
{% if subscriber.tags contains "TagName2" or subscriber.tags contains "TagName3" %}
```